# Values not inserted into my table in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

app/controller/CarrierController.php

here i am inserting to database table but not inserted and shows Unable to add your Details

database table fields id(auto increment ),fname,lname,dob,field,gender

```
class CarrierController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array('Session');


    var $uses=array('Carrier');
    public function index(){
    //  $this->set('posts', $this->carrier->find('all'));
        if($this->request->is('post')){
             Configure::read();
        pr($this->data); 
            $this->Carrier->create();

             if ($this->Carrier->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Details has been saved.'));
                 return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your Details'));
            }
            }
        }

}
```

app/view/Carrier/index.ctp

```
<h1>welcome to Carriers</h1>
<br />
<br/>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Carriers', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));?>
<table>
<tr><h3>Register here</h3></tr>

<tr><td>F.Name</td><td><?php echo $this->Form->text('fname'); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>L.Name</td><td><?php echo $this->Form->text('lname');?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Date Of Birth</td><td><?php echo $this->Form->date('dob');?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Degree</td><td><?php echo $this->Form->select('field', array('options' => array('B.E','B.sc','Mca','Mtech','Mba'),'empty' => '(choose)')); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Sex</td><td><?php
$options=array('M'=>'Male','F'=>'Female');
$attributes=array('legend'=>false);
echo $this->Form->radio('gender',$options,$attributes);
?></td></tr>
<tr><td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Carriers.Resume', array('between'=>'<br />','type'=>'file'));?></td></tr>

<tr><td><?php echo $this->Form->end('Apply');?></td></tr>



</table>
```

app/model/Carrier.php

```
<?php 
class Carrier extends AppModel{

    public $useTable='carrier'; //this is table name fields are inserted 
    }
?>
```

Comment: in form Carrier must be singular: form->create('Carrier') and so on...

Comment: If I remember you, you are doing the same mistakes again, table names should be plural, in your case carriers. You asked question yesterday about that I am sure. And for you question, you are trying to save file to db, which causes errors. You need to go through documentation a lot more before going into development so much.